# Show multiple locations on google Maps from Firestore Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to show the locations on google maps I am getting the longitutde and latitude from `Firestore`.

I created a struct in which I store latitude and longitude

```
struct Location {

var latitude: String = ""
var longitute: String = ""
}
```

And here is my firestore code to get the longitude and latitude

```
for document in snapshot!.documents {
self.location.append(Location(latitude: "\(document.data()["Latitude"] ?? "")", longitute: "\(document.data()["longitude"] ?? "")"))
print(self.location)

    guard let long = document.data()["Latitude"] as? String else { return}
    guard let lat = document.data()["longitude"] as? String else { return}
    let markerStart = GMSMarker(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(long) ?? 0.0, longitude: Double(lat) ?? 0.0))
    markerStart.map = self.mapView
}
```

I am getting locations in my console but when I converting it into Doubles trying to show it on google maps it is not working. Please help?[image]

```
 Document Value is ["userid": 24xDkrtBV6cJrBvRD3U0PmyBF3o2, "createddatetime": FIRTimestamp: seconds=1546584489 nanoseconds=461000000>, "user_role": sales man, "Latitude": 20.6108261, "longitude": 72.9269003, "batterypercentage": 66, "name": Keyur , "company_code": 001]
```

Comment: Please Print your document value.

Comment: @DixitAkabari...edited my question

Comment: are you check map load proper without adding marker?

Comment: It is loading properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have this data:

```
["userid": 24xDkrtBV6cJrBvRD3U0PmyBF3o2, "createddatetime": FIRTimestamp: seconds=1546584489 nanoseconds=461000000>, "user_role": sales man, "Latitude": 20.6108261, "longitude": 72.9269003, "batterypercentage": 66, "name": Keyur , "company_code": 001]
```

Instead of this kind of code:

```
for document in snapshot!.documents {
self.location.append(Location(latitude: "\(document.data()["Latitude"] ?? "")", longitute: "\(document.data()["longitude"] ?? "")"))
print(self.location)

    guard let long = document.data()["Latitude"] as? String else { return}
    guard let lat = document.data()["longitude"] as? String else { return}
    let markerStart = GMSMarker(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(long) ?? 0.0, longitude: Double(lat) ?? 0.0))
    markerStart.map = self.mapView
}
```

We can better it like so,

```
    for document in snapshot!.documents {
        self.location.append(Location(latitude: "\(document.data()["Latitude"] ?? "")", longitute: "\(document.data()["longitude"] ?? "")"))
        print(self.location)

        guard let latitude = document.data()["Latitude"] as? Double,
            let longitude = document.data()["Latitude"] as? Double else { return }

        let markerStart = GMSMarker(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
        markerStart.map = self.mapView
    }
```

The reason why the program does not reach the lines 72 73 74, is because of the `guard let`. It fails to convert to `String` your assumed `Double` latitude and longitude from your `document.data()`. Do it like my above code, and then you can improve it further as you want.

Comment: Actually it won't calling my codes after print statement :(

Comment: You just need to drag out (OR CLICK to disable) your breakpoint (That blue arrow)

Comment: Okay let me try that Sir :)

Comment: @wings No need for "sir". Read again my latest edit, with explanation as to why the program does not reach the lines 72, 73, and 74, like what you've mentioned. This should settle your problem.

Comment: Sir it is giving me two errors first is `Variable used within its own initial value` and one more to asking this `Expected ',' separator`

Comment: why is it asking me to convert this `Cannot convert value of type 'Any' to expected argument type 'CLLocationDegrees' (aka 'Double')`

Comment: I am getting all my locations but it is showing one incorrect location on map

Comment: @wings Are you done with this? Solved all problems? Sorry about my last edit. I forgot that your `document.data()` is a `[String : Any]` dictionary. Check how I cast the lat long to Double. If the numbers in the lat and long are correct and not mistakenly exchanged, then that should be fine, and if it's incorrect, then your data is just incorrect.